# Where are Galois's notes?

Tags: soft-question

There are a number of photos of bits of Galois's notes floating around online, such as [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/40213/40213-pdf.pdf?session_id=cacdcb683f105e0d90ea81986953ab5c38da2848) and [here](https://www.storyofmathematics.com/19th_galois.html). But where are the remaining originals, physically? I'm hoping what remained of them wasn't tossed out once photos were taken.

Comment: There’s a Math and Science History SE. You’ll probably get better help there.

Comment: [Close vote] This question potentially belongs on the HSM stackexchange: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ though HSM is not listed as an option for migrating questions to.

Comment: [Link to question on HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11198/where-are-galoiss-notes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MAA site has an [Index to Mathematical Treasures](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/index-to-mathematical-treasures), listing special collections of works by Galois.

- [Treatises on the Solution of Algebraic Equations.](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/mathematical-treasure-works-of-abel-and-galois) (German edition, 1889). This was a posthumously published collection of correspondence and research papers from 1828-1832 by Abel and Galois.
- [Works of Evariste Galois](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/mathematical-treasure-complete-works-of-evariste-galois) (French, 1887). A published collection of his works. This is one of the links in your answer and is also available on archive.org [(link)](https://archive.org/details/uvresmathmatiqu00frangoog/page/n1).

A site named 'Galois Group' [(Link)](http://www.galois-group.net/) apparently has an archive of Galois' notes and (now defunct) links to documents and school reports by Galois. The site is run by someone named Bernard Bychan [(Link to his website)](https://www.bychan.de/) and it mentions that:

> most of the original texts of Evariste Galois are not easily available, if you are not in working distance of Paris or at least a university with a huge library.

This suggests that Bychan knows where the notes are collected. So, you could potentially drop Bychan a message on the contact [(Link)](https://www.bychan.de/e2o.php) section of the site to ask.

To find works like these, it may be worth looking through the collections of university libraries and associated organisations. It may also be worth looking through biographies for references to original notes.